# data for testing graph alogrithms

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

i am looking for a source of huge data sets to test some graph algrothm implemention. The files should be in an easy to read file format somthing like:

$Node1

Node23

Node322334

Node43432

$Node2:

Node232

...

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Do you want a digraph or non-digraph, simple or non-simple, weighted or non-weighted? You can also consider generating your own dataset.

Comment: Ah sorry for the unprecise definition: I want digraphs, no-weighted.

Comment: Have you checked out Networkx for python: http://networkx.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

A quick python hack:

```
def generateGraph(n=100, avgNeigbors=10):
    from random import randint
    for i in range(n):
        print "$"+str(i)
        for m in range(avgNeigbors-randint(-avgNeigbors/2,avgNeigbors/2)):
            print (randint(0,n))
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this which may or may not contain what you need:

http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/datasets/graffiti/graffiti.html

http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/datasets/sgb/sgb.html

If you repost your question at https://math.stackexchange.com/ or at https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ you may attract the attention of algorithmic graph theorists or computer scientists specialising in graph algorithms.

Do post a link here if you repost your question as I'm slightly interested in where to obtain such dataset. Thanks.

Comment: Here you go: 

http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/739/data-for-testing-graph-alogrithms

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Facebook's [Graph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api) API?  It provides data in a JSON format, so it is very easy to read and should provide some large graphs depending on which data you query for.

Answer (score 0):

[IMDB](http://www.imdb.com)'s dataset can be used for free (non-commercially!) which can be [downloaded](http://www.imdb.com/interfaces#plain) in flat text files. It's huge: 100's of megabytes of raw text you can build a graph of.